# how can c++ compiler generate unicode string literals from a utf8 source file

Tags: c++, unicode

I am writing a program in c++ using gcc. I have an utf8 coded source file and I want string literals from my source file as UTF-16 strings. I use the gcc option -municode, which defines the UNICODE macro. String literals are still implemented as const char *. When I use TEXT("hello world"), it is still a const char *

Also, I would like to know which macro to define, or which commandline option to use, to have 16 bit traits in the std::string objects and al the template instantiations of the std library (I want std::char_traits to be of wchar_t.

Comment: Macros not necessary. More here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: I have used different sorts of string litteral modifiers like U, u, r. It is ignored by the compiler

Comment: Odd. What compiler?

Comment: I use g++ (minGW 64-bits edition on windows. The string litteral modifiers seem to work OK, I was mistaking. sorry

Comment: I thought gcc used 32-bit `wchar_t` rather than 16-bit as Microsoft does? In that case there may be no way to create UTF-16 literals.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, you can get UTF-16 strings even when `wchar_t` is 32 bits.

Comment: @MarkRansom gcc treats `wchar_t` as 32bit on non-Windows machines. It is still 16bit with MinGW (OP mentioned MinGW/Windows in comment) I am not sure about MinGW64, it must be similar to MinGW.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with C++11, there are ways to specify UTF-16 for both string literals and string objects. It introduces [`char16_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/char16_t) for UTF-16 characters, [`std::u16string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for UTF-16 strings, and the [`u` prefix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for UTF-16 literals.

```
std::u16string str = u"Hello World";
```

The compiler is responsible for converting the characters in your source code to the appropriate literal character values.